# Sum expansion of the elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: proof-writing, symmetric-polynomials

Recently I stumbled upon the following equation:

> $$e_k(V\cup W) = \sum_{i=0}^{|W|}e_{k-i}(V)e_i(W)$$

$V$ and $W$ are subsets of $\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$, and $V\cap W = \ \varnothing$. Where both $e_k(V)$ and $e_{k-i}(W)$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).

(**Question**) How would one prove this equation? My first attempt would be induction, but can it be done without induction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to quite some information that isn't contained in the question: what are $\;V, W\;$ , for example? How are we to understand that $\;e_k(V)\;$ is a symmetric polynomial? Symmetric... **on what**? On the set $\;V\;$ , in case it is a set?

Comment: Thank you, I did edit the question. and included a link to the elementary symmetric polynomial wikipedia. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: This is analogous to Vandermonde's identity, and the same [proof idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows since every $S \subseteq V \cup W$ can be decomposed uniquely into $S = S_1 \cup S_2$ where $S_1 \subseteq V$ and $S_2 \subseteq W$.  Explicitly,

\begin{align*}
e_k(V\cup W) &=  \sum_{S \subseteq V \cup W, \, |S| = k}  \prod_{x \in S} x\\
&= \sum_{S_1 \subseteq V, S_2 \subseteq W, |S_1 \cup S_2| = k}  \prod_{x \in S_1} x\prod_{y \in S_2} y\\
&= \ldots\\
\end{align*}

(steps left you to fill.) Note that setting all $x_i = 1$ recovers [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Alternatively: Consider the product $$\prod_{x \in V \cup W} (1 + x) = \left( \prod_{x \in V}(1+x) \right) \left( \prod_{y \in W}(1+y) \right)$$

and consider the degree-$k$ homogeneous component of both sides.